# How to pull jpg from a Blob Field in Delphi and display in a TImage?

Tags: delphi

I have the following code, but it doesn't display the jpg in the TImage:

```
  sf := TfrmSplash.Create(nil);
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    bf := TBlobField(dbfuncs.tblBlobs.FieldByName('BBlob'));
    bf.SaveToStream(ms);
    ms.Position := 0;
    sf.imgDisplay.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(ms);
    sf.Show;
    Sleep(2000);
  finally
    ms.Free;
    sf.Free;
  end;
```

Why doesn't this work?  I have jpeg in the uses clause of both forms involved.  But nothing is displayed in the image.....

Comment: See also [saving and loading image with ADO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11775398/757830)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you have to stream it into a TJPEG first, then assign that into the TImage? I don't have code handy here (though can dig it out later) but when I've done this in the past I'm pretty sure I have to do something like

```
MyJPeg.LoadFromStream
```

followed by

```
MyPicture.Graphic.Bitmap.Assign(MyJPeg)...?
```

Comment: Ok - I just tried that, but no go.  The jpg still doesn't appear in the TImage....

Comment: is there anything unusual about the TImage - are you creating it dynamically or is it an on-form component? Just wondering if there's a handle/parent problem. Can you temporarily hack your code to load a *bitmap* from a local file, just to test that the TImage will definitely show a graphic? Sorry if you've already tried/considered that!

Comment: rob, you're on to something - it's not displaying a bmp file that I know is good.  But I don't know why, it's just a standard TImage component....

Comment: If I switch to a ShowModal for the form, it shows the bmp file

Comment: Try a sf.imgDisplay.Refresh just after the show, it might simply be that it's not getting a chance to repaint the window.

Answer (score 2):

```
uses
   ... DB;

TBlobField(dbfuncs.tblBlobs.FieldByName('BBlob')).LoadFromFile('file name');
TBlobField(dbfuncs.tblBlobs.FieldByName('BBlob')).LoadFromStream();
```