# How to insert image into database using TADOQuery Component Only

Tags: delphi

I have one simple fundamental issue, I am trying to insert image into the database using `Insert` statement with other column values also using `TADOQuery` component.

Since the code is already written by somebody, some dummy sample code I would like to put here for your clarification with the respective steps.

Please note that this was working fine with `TQuery` component, since I am replacing `TQuery` with `TADOQuery` component, I must do the same using `TADOQuery` component only.

The same code should work for SQL Server as well as Oracle databases.

The datatype of the column in which I am trying to insert the image is of type `VarBinary` in SQL Server database.

Inserting an image into table using TQuery

1. Creating an image using `TImage`.

   ```
   msBinImgStream := TMemoryStream.Create; 
   imgCustom := TImage.Create(self); 
   imgJpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
   ```
2. Converting the image to `TJpegImage` and saving to `TMemoryStream`.

   ```
   imgJpg.Assign(imgCustom.Picture.Bitmap); 
   imgJpg.SaveToStream(msBinImgStream);
   ```
3. Inserting into the database by using `SetBlobdata` property of `TQuery` component.

   ```
   sSql := 'INSERT INTO Table_Name(Column1, Column2, Column_Image) VALUES ( ''' + Value1 + ''', ''' + Value2 + ''', :pBlob)'; 
   qryTQuery.SQL.Add(sSQL); 
   qryTQuery.ParamByName('pBlob').SetBlobData(msBinImgStream.Memory, msBinImgStream.Size); 
   qryTQuery.ExecSQL;
   ```

Now doing the same thing using `TADOQuery`:

1. Able to create the image.
2. Converting it to TJpeg and saving to `TMemoryStream`.
3. Trying to insert the image into database using `LoadFromStream(stream, ftBlob)` but getting an error *"String or binary value may be truncated"*.

   ```
   sSql := 'INSERT INTO Table_Name(Column1, Column2, Column_Image) VALUES ( ''' + Value1 + ''', ''' + Value2 + ''', :pBlob)'; 
   qryADOQuery.SQL.Add(sSQL); 
   qryADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('pBlob').LoadFromStream(msBinImgStream, ftBlob); 
   qryADOQuery.ExecSQL;
   ```

Kindly let me know, with this approach how should I overcome this issue.

Comment: r u sure that is binary blob, not text blob ? would covering image into base64 help ?

Comment: did you tried to google for the error ? https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=String+or+binary+value+may+be+truncated&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest It tells that your data column has length/size limitation in either server elvel or ADO level. Try smaller picture, would it fit ? Double check where you put the picture into.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Saving:

```
var
  Field: TBlobField;
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  if ADOQuery.Active and (Image.Picture.Graphic <> nil) then
  begin
    ADOQuery.Insert;
    Field := TBlobField(ADOQuery.FieldByName('ImageData')); // ensure it ís a blob
    Stream := ADOQuery.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmWrite);
    try
      Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(Stream);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
      ADOQuery.Post;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

or use a `TADOBlobStream` instead of a `TStream`:

```
var
  ...
  Stream: TADOBlobStream;
begin
  ...
    Stream := TADOBlobStream.Create(Field, bmWrite);
    ...
```

#### Loading:

```
var
  Field: TBlobField;
  Stream: TStream;
  Jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  if ADOQuery.Active then
  begin
    Field := TBlobField(ADOQuery.FieldByName('ImageData'));
    Stream := ADOQuery.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmRead);
    Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      Jpg.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      Image1.Picture.Graphic := Jpg;
    finally
      Jpg.Free;
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

When working with a parameter as you do, I think you have to provide it with additional settings like [`Attributes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TParameter.Attributes) and `DataType`, as follows:

```
  sSql := 'INSERT INTO Table_Name (Column1, Column2, Column_Image) ' +
    'VALUES (''' + Value1 + ''', ''' + Value2 + ''', :pBlob)';

  qryADOQuery.SQL.Add(sSQL);
  qryADOQuery.Parameters[0].Attributes := [paLong];
  qryADOQuery.Parameters[0].DataType := ftBlob; // Or ftVarBytes
                                                // Or ftOraBlob (Oracle only)
  qryADOQuery.Parameters[0].LoadFromStream(msBinImgStream, ftBlob);
  qryADOQuery.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: The issue is resolved as I have written the following statement before executing the Insert statement: 

Code: 

sSql := 'INSERT INTO Table_Name(Column1, Column2, Column_Image) VALUES ( ''' + Value1 + ''', ''' + Value2 + ''', :pBlob)'; 

qryADOQuery.SQL.Add(sSQL); 

qryADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('pBlob').Value := TBytesField(msBinImgStream).AsVariant; 

qryADOQuery.ExecSQL; 


But when I look into the database, the column in which I am storing the image, that shows as null, but when I run the application the image displays correctly. 

Any reason for this ? 


With Best Regards. 

Vishal