# Trying to save a .bmp from PC to a database blob field

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, stream, blob

I'm trying to save a .bmp from my PC to a database that contains a `blob` field.

I am currently working with code from here:

[How to insert image into database using TADOQuery Component Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773986/how-to-insert-image-into-database-using-tadoquery-component-only)

I've created a new form and added necessary components there.

This is how the form looks like:
[image]

- It contains the following: 3 `TButton`, 1 `TOpenDialog` and 1 `TImage`
- Button **Salveaza** (*Save*) is `Button3` and has `ModalResult` set to `mrOk`
- Button **Incarca Imagine** (*Load Image*) is `Button1`
- Button **Cancel** is `Button2`, has `Cancel` property ticked and has `ModalResult` set to `mrAbort`

The code for the **Incarca Imagine** (*Button1*) button is this:

```
procedure TaddImagineForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    end;
end;
```

The code for button named **Salveaza** (*Button3*) is:

```
procedure TaddImagineForm.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
          Field: TBlobField;
          Stream: TStream;
begin
          if dbmodule.comenziQuery.Active and (Image1.Picture.Graphic <> nil) then
          begin
             dbmodule.comenziQuery.Insert;
             Field := TBlobField(dbmodule.comenziQuery.FieldByName('pscreen')); // ensure it ís a blob
             Stream := dbmodule.comenziQuery.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmWrite);
             try
                Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(Stream);
             finally
                Stream.Free;
                dbmodule.comenziQuery.Post;
             end;
          end;
end;
```

- The `TSQLQuery` I'm using (named *comenziQuery*) is located on a `Data module`, along with other things I'm using (like `DataSource`, `DataSet`, `SQLConnection` and so on..) the Data module is named *dbmodule*
- The column in the database that should hold the .bmp image is named **pscreen** and is set as a `mediumblob` type.

**What should happen** (in probably my newbie point of view)

- The `blob` field named *pscreen* for the selected row should now contain the .bmp I selected previously with my `TOpenDialog`, by pressing the *Incarca Imagine* button

**What's actually hapenning**

- Once I click the *Save* button the form closes but the selected row doesn't get updated with the bmp image in it's blob field. No error, no warning, nothing. The field remains NULL for that row.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Dsm in the comments he pointed out that I'm using an insert, which adds a new record, not updates the one I'm selecting.
I'm referring to this line: `dbmodule.comenziQuery.Insert;`
Need to change the code somehow to update the record I'm selecting.

Extremely new to Delphi/SQL so I do apologize if it seems I'm banging my head against a wall and doing the exact opposite.

I'm using **Rad Studio 10 Seattle**, the database is `MYSQL`, the database components are located on a data module named dbmodule and contain the following: `TSimpleDataSet`, `TSQLQuery`, `TDataSource`, `TSQLConnection` - they are `dbExpress` components.

Thank you!

Comment: try reversing the dbmodule.comenziQuery.Post and Stream.Free

Comment: You are using an Insert. This adds an extra record to the database. Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: @Dsm - No, I'm basically trying to update a row that already exists in the database, specifically it's pscreen field which is currently null, I'd like to add the image there. I'm selecting it with the mouse, in my dbgrid, the row I wish to add the image to and firing up this form. Every row has an ID number contained in a field named id, if that helps.

Comment: That is my point. You are creating a new record and updating the blob field in that. Your current line will remain unchanged. You need to select the record represented by your line. I'm not familiar with ADO, but if it is a data-aware grid that you are using it might be as simple as deleting the insert line.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - nope, didn't change anything.

Comment: @Dsm - well it's not ADO, the example from the link i'm using is ADO, the component I'm using the code with is dbExpress (TSQLQuery vs TADOQuery). Tried removing the insert line, still no change. Gotta figure out how to change the code to select the record and update it

Comment: What is bmWrite? Why should it contain the picture you loaded?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - I'm trying to make this work using examples from searches I've found on the matter. Consequently I'm extremely new to this and most likely making mistakes :) So I'm sorry but I haven't gotten to the point where I actually know enough to answer your 2nd question(loaded question, right? ^_^). Sorry if this seems in any way offensive to any of you guys (asking for help like this and so on)

Comment: @tcsh - Sorry, disregard my comment. My recollection was wrong.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - No problem, it had me confused to hell anyway ^_^

Comment: LOL, sorry. I'll try to be more careful commenting.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked and was successful in providing the functionality that I needed

```
procedure TaddImagineForm.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
          Field: TBlobField;
          Stream: TStream;
begin
          dbmodule.comenziDataSet.Active := True;
          if (Image1.Picture.Graphic <> nil) then
          begin
             dbmodule.comenziDataSet.Edit;
             Field := TBlobField(dbmodule.comenziDataSet.FieldByName('pscreen')); // ensure it ís a blob
             Stream := dbmodule.comenziDataSet.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmWrite);
             try
                Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(Stream);
             finally
                Stream.Free;
                dbmodule.comenziDataSet.Post;
             end;
          end;
end;


end.
```

Just replaced using the Query with using the DataSet and that seems to have solved it, also my original post / question was wrong as I've been confusing the problems. Still, good for anyone going through the same.

Thanks to Sertac Akyuz