# How to implement Firebird Blob images in Delphi

Tags: delphi, blob, firebird

I've searched around but I can't find anything suitable for me. I found [this](http://codeprogrammer.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-use-blob-type-in-delphi.html), but it doesn't fit what I need.

I have a browse button with a .jpg filter, but I don't have a clue how to save the image to a blob field, then display onto a TImage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pull jpg from a Blob Field in Delphi and display in a TImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987917/how-to-pull-jpg-from-a-blob-field-in-delphi-and-display-in-a-timage)

Comment: Use the appropriate BLOB stream for your DB and call SaveToStream on the jpeg image. I guess.

Comment: @Marcus Adams, possibly yes, but I can't find the method to save it into field.

Comment: if the field has SaveToStream method - how do you think, does the field also have LoadFromStream method ? if the TPicture has LoadToStream method - how do you think, does it also have SaveToStream method ?
*And TBlobStream would probably be more shortcuting approach.*

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows how I save a picture into a blob field. qEditClass6Question is the field 'question' of the query qEditClass6. Once the picture is loaded into the blob field, the current tuple can be posted to the database.

```
Procedure TEditClassSix.LoadPic;
var
 j: TJPEGImage;

begin
 j:= TJPEGImage.Create;
 j.Assign (qEditClass6Question);
 image1.picture.assign (j);
end;
```